# react-native-fingerprint-scanner is not working

Tags: react-native

I have to implement fingerprint Authentication in my app , so i have installed react-native-fingerprint-scanner but the code is not working as i am getting this error

[image]

Here is my code

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import {
  Alert,
  Image,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  ViewPropTypes,
  StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';
import FingerprintScanner from 'react-native-fingerprint-scanner';
import ShakingText from './ShakingText';

class FingerprintPopup extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { errorMessage: undefined };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    FingerprintScanner
      .authenticate({ onAttempt: this.handleAuthenticationAttempted })
      .then(() => {
        this.props.handlePopupDismissed();
        Alert.alert('Fingerprint Authentication', 'Authenticated successfully');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message });
        this.description.shake();
      });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    FingerprintScanner.release();
  }

  handleAuthenticationAttempted = (error) => {
    this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message });
    this.description.shake();
  };

  render() {
    const { errorMessage } = this.state;
    const { style, handlePopupDismissed } = this.props;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={[styles.contentContainer, style]}>

          <Image
            style={styles.logo}
            source={require('../assets/finger_print.png')}
          />

          <Text style={styles.heading}>
            Fingerprint{'\n'}Authentication
          </Text>
          <ShakingText
            ref={(instance) => { this.description = instance; }}
            style={styles.description(!!errorMessage)}>
            {errorMessage || 'Scan your fingerprint on the\ndevice scanner to continue'}
          </ShakingText>

          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.buttonContainer}
            onPress={handlePopupDismissed}
          >
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
              BACK TO MAIN
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

FingerprintPopup.propTypes = {
  style: ViewPropTypes.style,
  handlePopupDismissed: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 164, 222, 0.9)',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  contentContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  },
  logo: {
    marginVertical: 45,
  },
  heading: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#00a4de',
    fontSize: 21,
  },
  description: (error) => ({
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: error ? '#ea3d13' : '#a5a5a5',
    height: 65,
    fontSize: 18,
    marginVertical: 10,
    marginHorizontal: 20,
  }),
  buttonContainer: {
    padding: 20,
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: '#8fbc5a',
    fontSize: 15,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});
export default FingerprintPopup;
```

I am getting this error react.PropTypes.oneOfType ,I am not sure where it is going wrong .

Please help me how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PropTypes are moved to individual library,

import it like this,

```
import PropTypes  from "prop-types";
```

you do not need to install it because it comes with react native

Comment: go to shaking text file, there also proptype is wrongly imported. correct it